# Flex Dynamically Created Components Added to Custom Components

Tags: apache-flex, flash, actionscript-3, actionscript

I am created a dynamically adding a VBox, that contains two images. Into a Custom Component that is derived from UIComponent. The problem is the Vbox that contains the two image is only a really tiny size. I would like the VBox stretch to the size of the two images.

**This is how I am creating the Vbox....**

```
var open:Image = new Image();
open.source = 'assets/icons/open.png';

var save:Image = new Image();
save.source = 'assets/icons/save.png';

var box:VBox = new VBox();
box.addChild(open);
box.addChild(save);
```

**The component is like this....**

```
public class MyComponent extends UIComponent
```

**I assign the VBox to the component like this(this is after the creationComplete event)**

```
public function set VBoxOptions(value:UIComponent) : void {
            if(_vBoxOptions){
                removeChild(_vBoxOptions);
            }
            _vBoxOptions = value;
            addChild(_vBoxOptions);
            invalidateSize();
        }
```

**In the update display list I do this..**

```
override protected function updateDisplayList(unscaledWidth:Number, unscaledHeight:Number):void {
   if(_hoverOptions)
  {
      _hoverOptions.move(unscaledWidth+2,2); //please note this is not the problem,
   }
}
```

**Thanks for help in Advance...**

Answer (score 0):

Do you need to extend UIComponent, because Canvas is going to get you there a lot quicker:

```
package
{
    import flash.events.Event;

    import mx.containers.Canvas;
    import mx.core.UIComponent;

    public class MyUIComponent extends Canvas
    {
        private var _vBoxOptions:UIComponent;

        public function MyUIComponent()
        {
            super();
        }

        public function set vBoxOptions(value:UIComponent):void
        {
            if(_vBoxOptions && this.contains(_vBoxOptions))
            {
                this.removeChild(_vBoxOptions);
            }

            _vBoxOptions = value;
            _vBoxOptions.validateNow();

            this.addChild(_vBoxOptions);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure if I can. But Anyway I would still like know what the issue is?

Comment: Canvas will dynamically resize to its contents (VBox does also). UIComponent does NOT resize to its contents. It is a shell. In this case it appears to be not resizing at all. This is why the components show up as expected when placed in a Canvas. Unless you have a specific need for UIComponent, just use Canvas.